# Azure Service Principal - permission to add members to an AD group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have created a Service Principal for Azure DevOps and trying to add a new member to AzureAD Group via DevOps Pipeline. The group contains only users until now. Here is what have already done:

- I have establish the ARM service link connection in Azure DevOps.
- I gave Service Principal the API permision to `group.readwrite.all` in `Active Directory/App registration/SP_name/Microsoft-Graph`
- I have run the script in a Azure CLI Shell in Azure DevOps: `az ad group member add --group XXX-YYY-groupname --member-id 111111-111-111-111-11111`

The DevOps pipeline fails with message:`ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`

What am I missing in delegating DevOps Service Principal to add members to my group?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In azure ad you need to "Grant Admin Permission" , its should work after that

Comment: @RahulShukla...granting admin permission will solve all the problems :P.

Comment: giving admin is not what somebody want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the permission you would need is `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All`. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#group-permissions):

> Allows the app to list groups, read basic properties, read and **update
> the membership of the groups the signed-in user has access to**. Group
> properties and owners cannot be updated and groups cannot be deleted.

Comment: should add member to the group work also from the CLI afterwards?

Comment: @PirvuGeorgian - So `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All` permission worked well for you?

Comment: Yes, it worked well, also as a task in an Azure DevOps pipeline. 
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId xxxx -RefObjectId yyyy

Comment: @PirvuGeorgian  Are you using an application to log in? I always thought that you are using user login. Sorry, if you use an app to log in, you only need `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the `Groups Administrator` role.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reading about `User Administrator` here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#user-administrator. It does not mention anything about adding users to group. Giving `Global Administrator` permission is an overkill IMHO as it will give all permissions.

Comment: @GauravMantri  Your suggestion is reasonable, I will revise the answer, thanks.

Comment: Not something that I would get accepted in the company and also not a good practice I guess. That’s why I was thought about something more granular.

Comment: @PirvuGeorgian - Agreed. Can you try `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All` as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @PirvuGeorgian  I updated the answer. By the way, if you use the `Azure CLI `command line, then granting the user the administrator role is indispensable.

Comment: @PirvuGeorgian  Of course, using [ms graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) can also meet your requirements. But for your question, you are using a script.

Comment: I have tested it with GroupMember.ReadWrite.All and with Powershell from the portal directly and seems not to work unfortunately. @GauravMantri

Comment: @CarlZhao why do you think is indispensable from AzureCLI? Group Administrator priviledges have only three people in the company, and no Apps allowed to have it

Comment: @PirvuGeorgian  Because I encountered the same error as you during the test. Then when I get the user administrator role, the script will run perfectly.

Comment: @PirvuGeorgian  If you cannot grant the user the user administrator role, then you can use ms graph api. They achieve the same result.